# Difference in event values with and without Campaign UTM in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a script in Python to extract the data from GA4 via API to play in a database.

However, both in the custom report and in the API, when I segment by Campaign, i.e. choose to bring the Campaign UTM values, it returns different.

**Custom Report with Campaign UTM:**

[image: Image 1]

**Personalized Report without Campaign UTM:**

[image: Image 2]

In both I'm segmented by the same date. It's a difference of 9,451 events, which for me in theory would be the campaigns with no campaign UTM value.

However, I need this value somehow, because I have a database that takes the UTM parameters from the URL and writes them to the database. In other words, if there are no parameters, it marks empty. And then when I set up the funnel to analyze this data, the data is discrepant.

When I extract the data via the GA4 API, the same thing happens. It gives this discrepancy between the event values of one table and another.

Does anyone know how to help me so that I have all the correct data, both what is assigned with UTM and what is not assigned with UTM, so that everything can be in the same table?